# How to create a library in NetBeans

Tags: java, netbeans, libraries

I have a class `Utilities.java` that I'd like to turn into a library that I can include in subsequent projects.

I did New project, Java class library and named the class `Utilities` and put it into the `C:\Users\Dov\Google Drive\NetBeansProjects\Utilities` folder.

In a new project, I tried to add the library via Libraries, Add jar/folder and gave the name `C:\Users\Dov\Google Drive\NetBeansProjects\Utilities\dist\Utilities.jar`, so under Libraries I then had `JDK 1.8` and `Utilities.jar`.

But I got errors (`cannot find symbol`) on all attempts to use methods in `Utilities.jar`.

What should I have done?

Comment: 1.) Are you using imports for your Class  </br>2.) Is your class and method PUBLIC?  </br> 3.) Open up your jar file with a compression utility like WinRar and see if class is there? If yes then in correct package structure?

Comment: Refer to my Answer below. Not sure what was wrong with original approach, but I'm OK. So, yes, I was using imports of public classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK. I deleted `Utilities.jar` from the `Libraries` folder, then right-clicked `Libraries` and this time selected `Add library...`, which opened dialog in which I clicked `Create library`.

I gave the new library the name `Utilties` and clicked `Add jar/folder`,then gave path to `jar` file: `C:\Users\Dov\Google Drive\NetBeansProjects\Utilities\dist\Utilities.jar`. Now I have in the Libraries folder a library named `Utilities - Utilities.jar` and all is well.